# How to generate diagram for multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, class, entity-relationship, diagram

I've 4 entity Funds, Composition, Instruments, Cash
I want to design a model with it possible one composition be a fund or an instrument or a cash

tables:

Funds(id_pk,name)

Composition(id_pk, units, and fk id to others tables (funds,instrument,cash)

Instrument(id_pk,name,maturity_date)
Cash(id_pk,name,currency)

### How can i design this???

```
@Entity
public  class Fund implements Serializable {


    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Composition.class)
    private Collection<Composition> composition1;
    public Fund(){
    }

   public Collection<Composition> getComposition1() {
        return this.composition1;
    }


  public void setComposition1 (Collection<Composition> composition1) {
        this.composition1 = composition1;
    }

@Entity
public  class Instrument implements Serializable {

    public Instrument(){

    }
}
@Entity
public  class Cash implements Serializable {

    public Cash(){

    }
}

@Entity
public  class Composition implements Serializable {


    @OneToOne(targetEntity=Fund.class)--????
    private Object position --here is my problem . may be Fund, Cash or Instrument

    public Composition(){

    }

}
```

Comment: This is too vague and not a programming specific question.  What have you tried so far?  What database system are you using?  If you've attempted it yourself, we'd actually need to see the SQL code that's causing you troubles.

Comment: Jimmy. I change to see the specific code. My problem is how to desing this in Class and SQL